# Call Android Activity from inside?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Is it possible to call an `Activity` form inside the `Activity` class, so I can deliver information over constructor?

something like

```
public MyClass(){
     startActivity(new Intent(this, this.getClass()));
}
```

Comment: why on earth you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is because you want to pass some initialisation data to the activity?

The way to do this is by adding a Bundle to the activity.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(YourStartingActivity.this,YourNewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", "value");
    startActivity(intent);
```

The in the OnCreate method of your new Activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String myString = bundle.getString("key");
```

Which will get whatever you passed in as your "value" which can be a String, int, float etc....

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that. If I understood correctly you want to pass data between two activities, you should always do this via Intent. Take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/3707606

If you want to pass more complex data you should make the data class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). It may look hard but you can generate your parcelable at http://www.parcelabler.com/ or install this [plugin](https://github.com/mcharmas/android-parcelable-intellij-plugin) to Android Studio.